# Highlighting #text (comments) in spyder (python 3.6)

Tags: spyder

Is there a way to highlight comments--like in word or adobe--in spyder (or maybe in an different IDE?)

Answer (score 3):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Sorry, there's no way to highlight specific words in Spyder. However, you can add comments like `# TODO` `# FIXME` whose line will be shown with a blue check mark next to it.

You can find all the special annotations we support in the menu

`Tools > Preferences > Editor > Advanced settings > Annotations`

Comment: I found them in `Spyder 4` under `Tools → Editor → Advanced Settings → Annotations`

Comment: @Jabro same for `Spyder 5`. This should be preferably an edit to this answer or a new answer.